# text file into array C++

Tags: c++

I have a data.txt file like this

```
 1 9
 2 5
 3 4
 4 3
 5 2
 6 1
```

now i want to put it into my array which is about obstacle

and i want to put the values is my obstacle as

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 5 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 9 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 5 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 1 
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

like this. how to do this?

I'm very bad about SSCCE. but i uploaded my code for you to get the gist of it.

```
int main()
{
    int i,j,x,y,x1,y1;

    for(i=0; i < 12; ++i)
        for(j=0; j < 12; ++j)  RES[i][j]=0;  // way
    RES[1][5]=3;                         // start
    RES[10][5]=5;                        // goal
    RES[3][4]=RES[3][5]=RES[3][6]=2;     // block
    x=1;
    y=5;


    for(i=0; i < 12; ++i)
        for(j=0; j < 12; ++j)  R[i][j]=254;  // walkable

    R[1][5]=253;                         // start
    R[10][5]=0;                          // finish

    R[3][4]=R[3][5]=R[3][6]=255;         // pathless, bunker

    for(j=0; j < 12; ++j)  R[0][j] =255;
    for(j=0; j < 12; ++j)  R[11][j]=255;
    for(i=0; i < 12; ++i)  R[i][0] =255;
    for(i=0; i < 12; ++i)  R[i][11]=255;

    ofstream RRR;
    RRR.open("OutWalk.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    if(!RRR) RRR.open("OutWalk.txt", ios::out);


    for(N=0; N < Nmax; ++N)
    {
        cout<<"  N = " << N << endl;
        for(i=1; i < 11; ++i)
            for(j=1; j < 11; ++j)
            {

                if(R[i][j] == N)
                {
                    if(R[i+1][j] == 253)
                    {
                        x=i+1;    // start
                        y=j;
                        goto PATH;
                    }
                    if(R[i+1][j] == 254) R[i+1][j]=N+1;
                    if(R[i-1][j] == 253)
                    {
                        x=i-1;    // start
                        y=j;
                        goto PATH;
                    }
                    if(R[i-1][j] == 254) R[i-1][j]=N+1;
                    if(R[i][j+1] == 253)
                    {
                        x=i;    // start
                        y=j+1;
                        goto PATH;
                    }
                    if(R[i][j+1] == 254) R[i][j+1]=N+1;
                    if(R[i][j-1] == 253)
                    {
                        x=i;
                        y=j-1;
                        goto PATH;
                    }
                    if(R[i][j-1] == 254) R[i][j-1]=N+1;            // start

                };

            }; // R[12][12]
    };    // N



PATH:
    if(R[x+1][y] > R[x-1][y])
    {
        x1=x-1;
        y1=y;
    }
    else
    {
        x1=x+1;
        y1=y;
    }
    if(R[x1][y1] > R[x][y+1])
    {
        x1=x;
        y1=y+1;
    }
    if(R[x1][y1] > R[x][y-1])
    {
        x1=x;
        y1=y-1;
    }
    RES[x1][y1]=1;
    if(R[x1][y1] == 0)
    {
        RES[x1][y1]=5;
        goto END;
    }
    x=x1;
    y=y1;
    goto PATH;


END:
    cout << "  N = " << N << endl;
    RRR << endl;

    RRR << endl;
    RRR << " Number of circuit = " << N << "  Goal: x = "<< x1 << " y = "<< y1 << endl;
    for(i=10; i > 0; i--)
    {
        RRR << endl;
        for(j=1; j < 11; ++j) RRR << R[i][j] << " \t ";
    }
    RRR << endl;
    for(i=10; i > 0; i--)
    {
        RRR << endl;
        for(j=1; j < 11; ++j) RRR << RES[i][j] << "  ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part are you stuck on?

Comment: my task is to create obstacle for shortest path and to show the path as binary and print it to a txt file. I can do that , but i have a data file given above that is my obstacle. and i don't know how put it in place of obstacle as like the 2nd matrix.
any type of help is much appriciated.

Comment: if you need the code to understand i can upload it.

Comment: You should post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) *in* the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way to make the pattern you want from the data you have. I'm going to use an array rather than reading from a file, but it shouldn't be hard to do that if you want to.

Basically, the trick is to look at the index of each item at each position in the output. If, instead of outputting the actual value you want, you look at the index of the value in the array, it looks like this:

```
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 
5 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 
5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

So now, think about what the coordinates of each position are. If we write it out as the coordinates, it looks like this:

```
<0,0> <1,0> <2,0> <3,0> <4,0> ... etc.
<0,1> <1,1> <2,1> <3,1> <4,1> ... etc.
<0,2> <1,2> <2,2> <3,2> <4,2> ... etc.
<0,3> <1,3> <2,3> <3,3> <4,3> ... etc.
... etc.
```

So how do those coordinates match up with the indexes? We obviously want the relationship to have something to do with their distances from the center of the square. So let's subtract out the center coordinate from all the other coordinates:

```
<-5,-5> <-4,-5> <-3,-5> <-2,-5> ... etc.
<-5,-4> <-4,-4> <-3,-4> <-2,-4> ... etc.
<-5,-3> <-4,-3> <-3,-3> <-2,-3> ... etc.
<-5,-2> <-4,-2> <-3,-2> <-2,-2> ... etc.
...etc.
```

So what's the relationship? Notice how all along the top and left edge, there's a `-5`? And we want our outermost result to be `5`. And in all of the 2nd row and 2nd column, there's a `-4`. We want the rest of those values to be a `4`. So a pattern's emerging here. It looks like you need to take the maximum of the absolute value of the coordinate to figure out the index. Then use the index to get the value to put there.

So putting it all together, it would look something like this (I substituted reading from a file for just using an array, but you can build the array from the file) :

```
    int distances[] = { 9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    const int centerX   = 5;
    const int centerY   = 5;

    for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 11; y++)
        {
            int largest = std::max (abs(x - centerX), abs(y - centerY));
            std::cout << distances [ largest ] << " ";
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped.

Comment: hello user1118321, i have a question. if have 5 arbitrary elements in the array, then how should I change this code to get the same pattern. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you clarify? Whatever you have in your array determines the pattern produced. So if you have { 1, 3, 16, 27, 4 }, then you'll get those values distributed into the concentric squares the code produces. (You'll probably need to change the formatting if you have 2-digit values.) Or did you mean something else?

Comment: i got it cleared. but as you can see above, in my code for bunker i have to input this algorith you send. Now i'm having trouble implementing it into the code.